# Replace WCF NetNamedPipeBinding

Tags: c#, wcf, ipc

I'm using a WCF service with NetNamedPipeBinding for IPC. This prevents the code to be updated to .Net 7 so I want to replace the WCF server with a client compatible solution. I can't afford breaking changes, so replacing server and client with sth else is no option.

Getting the windows name of the named pipe works

```
//localhost replaced by + or *, capitals, trailing slash
string normalizedName = "net.pipe://+/SOME/PATH/";
var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(normalizedName));
string namedPipeMMFName = string.Format(@"Global\net.pipe:E{0}", base64);
```

For the server

```
mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen(namedPipeMMFName, 20, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite);
{
    using (var accessor = mmf.CreateViewAccessor(0, 20, MemoryMappedFileAccess.Write))
    {
        //Reverse engineered. Meaning unclear
        accessor.Write(0, 1);
        accessor.Write(1, 0);
        accessor.Write(2, 0);
        accessor.Write(3, 0);

        Guid pipeGuid = Guid.NewGuid();

        accessor.Write<Guid>(4, ref pipeGuid);
        retVal = pipeGuid.ToString();
    }
}
```

For the client

```
using (var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting(namedPipeMMFName, MemoryMappedFileRights.Read))
{
    using (var accessor = mmf.CreateViewAccessor(4, 16, MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read))
    {
        accessor.Read(0, out Guid pipeGuid);
        retVal = pipeGuid.ToString();
    }
}
```

The server now looks like that

```
var pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream(pipeName, PipeDirection.InOut, maxNumberOfServerInstances, PipeTransmissionMode.Message, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);
pipeServer.BeginWaitForConnection(WaitForConnectionCallBack, null);
```

When the client (WCF!) opens the connection the new server recognizes it and begins to read.
After calling EndRead() I get the first result

```
"\0\u0001\0\u0001\u0002\u0002\u0019net.pipe://localhost/IF13\u0003\b\f"
```

which looks like sth from the client. Further read calls result in no data as if the pipe was closed by the client

I expect that WCF client requires some kind of hand shake.
What do I have to answer after the first successful read?

Thanks
Tom

Comment: Do you mean that you don't understand the meaning of the data received from the server on the client-side and you want to know how to understand the code above.

Comment: Its the data (or handshake). The code is pretty easy. I want to get to the point where the SOAP messages are sent back and forth

Comment: In this case, I think [AfterReceiveRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/message-inspectors) in Message Inspector is for you.

Comment: @Jiayao Correct. The messages to send are clear. Problem is that some dark magic happens before that. That's what I need to know

Comment: Is there any progress on this issue.